# Multihomed Windows 2016 Server default route ignoring metrics/preference

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2016, routes

I have a host with two NICs, both have internet access but I'm trying to manually set preference of a specific NIC.

My interface metrics:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> Get-NetIPInterface -ConnectionState Connected -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet*"  | Format-Table;

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
10      Ethernet 5                      IPv4                  1500               1 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
3       Ethernet 2                      IPv4                  1500               1 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
```

NetRoute:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>  Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix "0.0.0.0/0" | Format-Table;

ifIndex DestinationPrefix                              NextHop                                  RouteMetric PolicyStore
------- -----------------                              -------                                  ----------- -----------
10      0.0.0.0/0                                      10.0.20.1                                          2 ActiveStore
3       0.0.0.0/0                                      172.25.1.1                                        10 ActiveStore
```

route print (which seems to be NetIPInterface metric + NetRoute metric):

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.25.1.1      172.25.1.89     11
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.0.20.1      10.0.23.243      3
```

but then:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> (Find-NetRoute -remoteIpAddress 8.8.8.8)[1]

ifIndex DestinationPrefix                              NextHop                                  RouteMetric PolicyStore
------- -----------------                              -------                                  ----------- -----------
3       0.0.0.0/0                                      172.25.1.1                                        10 ActiveStore
```

the route with gw "10.0.20.1" has a lower metric, why isn't this the next hop?
I DONT have a more specific route for "8.8.8.8".

I've tried this:
`netsh interface ip delete destinationcache`.
but nothing changed.

Comment: I've also tried increasing the InterfaceMetric of the undesired interface, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you double check that the gateway is reachable on Interface 10 (Ethernet 5) ? Can you try to disconnect Interface 3 and see if Interface 10 is selected by Find-NetRoute when Interface 3 is not available?